# Error while installing mongodb-community using Homebrew

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

**Hello, i'm getting this error while i'm trying to install MongoDB using Homebrew.**

```
Updating Homebrew...

==> Installing mongodb-community from mongodb/brew

Error: An exception occurred within a child process:

  NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass

Did you mean?  paths
```

your help please!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several trying and searching in web, i resolved finally the problem just by installing the last version of xcode command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

I literally faced the same issue today morning, I installed all software updates and nothing worked. Someone mentioned using `brew update` nothing.

```
softwareupdate --all --install --force
```

Running `brew doctor` asked to clear out command-line tools and reinstall `xcode`

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

I did the same, followed by installing mongo community edition, it worked!